# Error Message Styling in Trinidad

Tags: jsf-1.2, trinidad

I am using JSF 1.2 with apache Trinidad.I have used the following to take date as input

```
<tr:inputDate label="Date From"  value="#{someBean.fromDate}">

                <tr:convertDateTime messageDetailConvertDate="Invalid Date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>

                </tr:inputDate>
```

After doing this I can see the error message when I enter invalid date.But the problem is I can not find an attribute to plug css style to

```
<tr:convertDateTime >.
```

I tried to keep the tr:convertDateTime tag in a div class and applied css styling to it but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can style it with the selectors you can find here:
http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/skin-selectors.html